# set java script value to url param - java

Tags: java, jsp, url, taglib, url-parameters

I am using this taglib : `<%@ taglib prefix="sUrl" uri="http://www.emudhra.com/jsp/jstl/secureUrl" %>`

And opening a popup window with few values passed :

```
function editStatus(tranId,offerCode,userId){
```

will I be able to convert these values to java and assign them to param ??

```
    var target =  "<sUrl:url value='/admin/editStatusPopUp.htm' encryptionEnabled='true'><sUrl:param name='tranId' value='"+tranId+"'/> <sUrl:param name='offerCode' value='"+offerCode+"' /><sUrl:param name='userId' value='"+userId+"' /></sUrl:url>";
    window.open(target,'SearchPopUpName' ,'toolbar=no,scrollbars=0,location=no,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=no,width=350,height=170');
}
```

but whatever values I set to `url param` it is not getting set exactly `tranId,offerCode,userId` are not getting set and I get this kind when I see the server console :

```
tranId:"+tranId+"
offerCode:"+offerCode+"
userId:"+userId+"
```

How do I set values to `param`?

Comment: ... Your JSP tags are evaluated on the *server* side. Your JS function is evaluated on the *client* side. Build the final URL on the client; create the base URL either on the server, or as a standalone JS value to which you append the JS-based parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton understood this. can i convert javascript values to java variables and set them to url param ?

Comment: No, for the same reason. I'm not quite sure I understand the issue--all you're doing is appending URL-escaped parameters to a URL. Why wouldn't `var foo = '<sUrl:url value="..."/>';` work, then in the JS function you append URL-escaped JS parameters to that URL?

Comment: I think he's trying to encrypt the URL parameters on the client side in Javascript using a Java Taglib.  Obviously this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

If these values (tranId,offerCode,userId) are known to you before generating the page, then change all your

```
value='"+tranId+"'/>
```

to

```
value='<%=tranId%>'/>
```

for each variable.  But this effectively means your Javascript function will now be

```
function editStatus(){
```